# Teststack.White not always finds Tab's child control

Tags: c#, ui-automation

Got some random issue with finding control. Issue happens with control that is located in the tab. I do use some logic to select the tab if not selected and get the control. For example I got 3 ribbon tabs in WPF application:

```
mTarget.Tabs.ATab.FindTab();
mTarget.Tabs.ATab.SelectTab();
mTarget.Tabs.ATab.FindAndValidateTreeView();
```

Code always finds the tab using title text in FindTab() method:

```
var criteria = SearchCriteria.ByText(mTabTitle);
mTabPage = mMainWindow.Get<TabPage>(criteria);
```

But not always finds a control inside the tab when tab is already selected before the test:

```
// TreeView
var mTree = TabPage.Items.Find(x => x.Id == TabNames.TREE_ID && x.Name == TabNames.TREE_ID) as Tree;
```

Similar random issue I get with other controls like Ribbon groups when looking child controls. The only thing I noticed that if I select another tab and re-run the test won't fail.

Why this happens and how to get round this issue??
I use default White's settings on caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may fail to find a control second time so I had to improve my code by converting to class variable once it is already found:

```
// TreeView
if (mTree == null)
    mTree = TabPage.Items.Find(x => x.Id == TabNames.TREE_ID && x.Name == TabNames.TREE_ID) as Tree;
```